# Javascript instanceof doesn't work as my expectation

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am learning javascript and wrote below code.

```
var Parent = (function() { return function() {};})();
var Child = (
    function() { 
        return function(p) {
            var F = new Function();
            F.prototype = p.prototype;
            Child.prototype = new F();
        };
    })();

var p = new Parent();
var c = new Child(Parent);
console.log(p instanceof Parent);
console.log(c instanceof Parent);
```

c instanceof Parent returns false, which doesn't match my expectation!!

Then I change the code to:

```
var Parent = (function() { return function() {};})();
var Child = (function() { return function() {};})();
var F = new Function();
F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
Child.prototype = new F();
var p = new Parent();
var c = new Child();
console.log(p instanceof Parent);
console.log(c instanceof Parent);
```

This time c instanceof Parent returns true.
Who can answer why?

Comment: Because in your first code you set prototype inside the constructor (and proper indentation would make the problem more obvious).

Comment: @zerkms yes, I notice I set prototype inside the constructor, I would like to know why this way results in wrong result

Comment: Why all the self-calling anonymous functions? Why not just define `function Parent(){}` etc? have you been reading too much Crockford?